# Maximize $a_1^{a_2^{\ldots^{a_n}}}$, where $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ is a permutation of $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$

Tags: optimization, permutations, power-towers

You are given a tuple of integers $B=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$.

Find $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ - a permutation of $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ - that maximizes $a_1^{a_2^{\ldots^{a_n}}}$.

For example -

If $B=(5, 6, 4)$, then the answer is $(4 ,5, 6)$.

If $B=(2,3)$, then the answer is $(3,2)$.

**Note** - 
Power is calculated in order given below

$a_1^{(a_2^{(\ldots^{a_n})})}$.

Comment: $\{\}$ denotes sets, not $k$-tuples. You meant $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$. The order doesn't matter, so $B=\{5,6,4\}=\{6,5,4\}$. Even then, why is the answer to the last one $(2,3)$ and not $(3,2)$? We have $3^2>2^3$.

Comment: My bad. gave answer in wrong order. Fixed it.

Comment: I've change the $\{\}$ notation to $()$, since no one denotes tuples by $\{\}$, since this is the standard notation for sets. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

Comment: Only good answer for this which I can think of is "it depends".

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: Except for $2^3$, that seems to be an exception, I would put them in increasing order, $a_1<a_2<a_2<\dots$.

Comment: what do you expect the elements $a_i$ to be :integers,positive integers,reals.. because it depends on the the set we are working in e.g. (4,0.5) is better then (0.5,4) (-1,2) is better then (2,-1) (if you allow negative integers there will be a lot of cases), and because your definition of the objectif is recursive so the first case you may study is $n=2$ and i think that the generalization will be easy

Comment: @user314 it was asked in one of the programming competitions.

Comment: Finally I got the answer after spending 6 hours.

Comment: @xoff your solution will fail if one of the numbers is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the answer for audience-

1. Sort the numbers $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$ in decreasing order.Lets call it Seq.
2. Let answer be A. All the 1s to A and remove them from Seq.
   i.e If Seq is 4,3,2,1,1
   then after step 2 seq will be 2,3,4
   and A = 1,1
3. if first element in Seq is 3 and second element is 2 then remove both from Seq and add 2,3 to A
4. Add rest of the elements from Seq to A.
5. Reverse the numbers in A

Let me know if you find anything wrong in given solution.